# Visual Studio 2019 ignoring formatting

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, settings

Since upgrading to Visual Studio Community 2019 16.5.3, Visual Studio has been ignoring my (The default) formatting rules, specifically relating to curly braces (dotnet core 3.1)

The expected behaviour is that curly braces will auto-new line as such:

```
public void ExpectedBehaviour()
{
    DoStuff();
}
```

However they are autoformatted to:

```
public void ActualBehaviour() {
    DoStuff();
}
```

I have tried setting/unsetting this manually in Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Code Style -> Formatting

but this has not helped.

Comment: ... `Code Style -> Formatting -> New Lines`

Comment: as I said, I've already tried this, to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

If you have adjusted the formatting settings and it still isn't working, you may have a [.editorconfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2019) file over riding it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have an editorconfig file for this project.